# Installed Windows 8.1 on Mac Air withouth Bootcamp drivers

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

During the installation, Mac asked to install Bootcamp drivers, but I chose to skip this step and just install Windows. However, now Windows does not work well.

Some problems I've noticed are:

1. No sound
2. Bad video performance
3. No right-click functionality on trackpad

How can I install the drivers now, after having installed Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Use [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048) to identify your machine and OS installed. Aside from two of the most recent Macbooks, Bootcamp v4 and v5 support software drivers are available. Download from there and run using the instructions supplied in the DL doc.